# line integral in vector field: non-parameterized vs parameterized

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Given:

(1) Vector Field $\vec{W} = (y, x)$

(2) Curve C is a line segment along the x-axis from point:(0,0) to point:(a,0).

---

**I'm trying to solve the following line integral in a vector field two ways:**

$$
I = \int_{C} \vec{W} \cdot d\vec{s}
$$

---

**First Way**: (without parameterization)

$$I = \int_{C} \vec{W} \cdot d\vec{s} = \int_{C} (y, x) \cdot (dx, dy)$$
$$I =\int_{0}^a y\ dx + \int_0^0 x\ dy $$
$$I =\int_{0}^a y\ dx$$
$$I =[yx]^{a}_{0} $$
$$I =ax - 0x$$
$$I =ay $$

**Second Way**: (with parameterization)

$$\psi(t) = (t,0)$$
$$ 0 \le t \le a$$

$$\frac{\psi(t)}{dt} = (1,0)$$

$$\vec{W}(\psi(t)) = (0, t)$$

$$I = \int_{C} \vec{W} \cdot d\vec{s} = \int_{t_0}^{t_1} \vec{W}(\psi(t)) \cdot \frac{d\psi}{dt}\ \ dt$$

$$I = \int_{a}^{0} (0,t) \cdot (1,0)\ dt$$

dot product is zero, therefore integral is zero.

$$I = 0$$

---

**My question is this:**

Why do these two ways of integrating obtain different values for I?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can notice that when you do the second step the first way, i.e. $\int_0^a y\,dx~$, the $x$ is a dummy variable but the $y$ although being a variable yet just stays zero. Thus, plug $y=0$ into the integral.